# Content Positioning trick on bootstrap

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

Please check this HTML template  first [Clippinghand](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/159789737/Clippinghand/index.html)

My problem is on what we provide's content below. There is first image then posts and next is first post then image like that 6 Element i took. On Computer type devices things are okay but when I'm going to make it responsive for mobile or tab devices it's making problem and the problem is images and content are getting closer i just always want to make them top of the posts I mean i want my images top of the post all of, How could i do that? Is there any trick ? Also How i can Do complete this section with only one custom post ?
[Here is an example on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKipl.png)

Comment: Live site is ok, but you can't really work and save there. Use the code snippet provided by Stack Overflow to explain the issue. Therefore...

I think your problem relates to the html elements position within your page. If you're using Bootstrap and the default column layout, every column is floated to the left. Use pull and push classes to reverse the order in the row for smaller devices.

This issue has already been discusses here several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Column Ordering via [Push + Pull](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) which is built into Bootstrap. You'll have to reorder your content to achieve this. Here a good [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap) also.

Basically stack the column content in the opposite order and apply push and pull classes. (*instead of content 1 then content 2, stack content 2, then content 1 inside your col-md-6). See working example and it will be illustrated.

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="our-services">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row red">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="img-one">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content-one">
          <h4>Background Remove</h4>
          <em>Price starts from $0.49</em>

          <p>This is the most demandable and most used image editing service all over the world for ecommerce product selling. Don’t worry, we make it easy to ensure all your images fit your ecommerce image editing guideline. We resize, crop, remove borders,
            and remove image background turning it to pure white, transparent or color background as per your guideline.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row blue">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
        <div class="img-two">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
        <div class="content-two">
          <h4>Web-ready Images</h4>
          <em>Price starts from $1</em>

          <p>For web-shop owners, we introduce our additional delivery of web-ready images. Add the image specifications (like crop size 800×800 px ) and we will deliver web-ready image. We can fulfill the image size requirements for any ecommerce platform
            like Amazon, eBay, Shopify, bigcommerce, volusion, squarespace etc.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row red">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="img-three">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content-three">
          <h4>Multiple Mask</h4>
          <em>Price starts from $2</em>

          <p>If you want to separate and modify different parts and features of the same product including its color, shape, and size, Multipath is the service you can take from us. We can deliver images with Alpha Channel, Layer Mask or Only Path.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row blue">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
        <div class="img-four">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
        <div class="content-four">
          <h4>COLOR MATCHING</h4>
          <em>Price starts from $2</em>

          <p>You have many different color variations of the same product but do not want to spend time taking photos of each one of them? No worries! You don’t have to. We can change the color and size of the same product as per your instruction to save
            you from investing more of your time and money in taking photos.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- End of Our services area -->
```

Comment: Just that i was looking for ! It's build in i didn't know.. I just crashed my mind by thinking about. You save my lot of time thank you dear.. Before Of it I used display block and none property by doubling the content .. I knew that was so bad but i did it like that way.. Not it's got too easy to make.

Comment: It's Just worked Perfectly.. Thanks man once again. Check it out You will feel proud.. hahahha [PushPull](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/159789737/Clippinghand/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/mwvfteuq/

In two words, you need to place your `divs` in the order you want them to appear on the smallest screen. For wider devices you can play with `float` set to `left` or `right` (`pull-left` and `pull-right` in bootstrap) to customize elements position in a row. Revoke those properties using media queries for the smallest screen.

For example:

**HTML** (using bootstrap)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right right">img</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">some stuff</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">img</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">some stuff</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    div.right{
        float:none !important;
    }
}
```

*Do not forget to use `!important` to override bootstrap `pull-right` property*

Comment: Wow, Thank you ! Your answer is of course helpful and useful. Thank once again.